# Extracting X_train and y_train from tabular data where a column is target and another columns are features with its corresponding ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tabular

I have this DataFrame:

| timestep | ID | x1 | x2 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

I expect it converted to the numpy ndarray `X_train` with shape (9, 24, 2).
Where, `9` represent how many IDs. `24` represent `n-rows` aka `timestep`. `2` represents how many features (x1 and x2)

It same to the `y_train` with shape `(9, 1)` where 9 represents how many IDs and 1 represents scalar value since all `y` will be same for all 24 timesteps

The minimal reproducible example for this, when accessing
`X_train[0,:,:]` it will returns table with `ID=1` with 24 rows (timesteps) like this:

| x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| ... | ... |
| 5 | 5 |

(the last 24-th row)

Comment: What's your question? Have you _tried_ converting this data to the numpy ndarray `X_train` with shape (9, 24, 2)? Did your code work?

Comment: @ForceBru I can do it if the IDs was separated, but the ID represent different context for single table. So that's mean I must segmenting a big table into smaller table where a table represent an ID

Comment: Please post a [mcve], explain what doesn't work and what your question is.

Comment: Your input is ambiguous, is any combination missing or do you have all 216 of them as rows?

Answer (score 2):

First sort the rows by ID/timestep with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then convert [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
out = (df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestep'])[['x1', 'x2']]
         .to_numpy().reshape((9, 24, 2))
       )
```

Or, for an arbitrary number of features/columns:

```
n = df[['ID', 'timestep']].nunique()

out = (df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestep'])
         .filter(like='x')
         .to_numpy().reshape((n['ID'], n['timestamp'], -1))
       )
```

*NB. assuming no combinations of ID/timestamps is missing/duplicated*

For `y`, since the IDs are already sorted:

```
y_train = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID')['y'].to_numpy()
```